# Laravel Echo Cant subscribe a Chanel Using websocket Laravel(Beyondode)

Tags: laravel, websocket, echo, laravel-echo

Im triying using blade(not using vue component) but still im using vue.js in declare it

**This is my botstrap.js**

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo";
window.Pusher = require("pusher-js");
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: "pusher",
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY
});
```

**This is my app.js**

```
require("./bootstrap");

window.Vue = require("vue");
```

**blade.php**

```
<div id="app2">
    <div class="header-tab-content" id="tab-3" style="">

            <div class="bg-detail">


                <div class="bottom-20" v-for="val in bidComments">

                    <div class="timeline-item top-15">
                         <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                        <div class="timeline-item-content-full">
                            <p class="bid bid-user">
                               @{{val.user.name}}
                            </p>
                            <p>
                               @{{val.comment}}
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <h5 class="font-11 small-text timeline-reply"><i class="fa fa-clock timeline-icon"></i>@{{val.created_at}}
                            <span><i class="fa fa-reply timeline-icon"></i>Balas</span>
                            <span><i class="fa fa-heart timeline-icon"></i>Suka</span>
                        </h5>

                        <div class="clear"></div>

                    </div>


                    <div class="clear"></div>

                </div>

                <div class="decoration bottom-10 top-20 deco-green"></div>

                <div class="content-title m0 bottom-0">
                    <span class="color-highlight top-10">Tulis Komentar</span>
                    <h1 class="m0">&amp; Pertanyaan</h1>

                    <div class="input-simple-2 input-green bottom-10 top-5">
                        <div class="btn-comment-upload">
                            <label for="upload" class="d-inline-block">
                                <i class="fa fa-camera"></i>
                            </label>
                            <input type="file" name="" id="upload">
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Tulis Komentar" class="input-comment" v-model="commentBox">
                        <div class="btn-comment-send">
                            <a href="#" class="header-icon f-18" @click.prevent="postComment"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- <div class="input-simple-2 input-green bottom-10 top-5">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Tulis penawaran, contoh : KB 400">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-simple-2 input-green bottom-0 top-5">
                        <textarea class="contactTextarea requiredField" placeholder="Tulis komentar kamu disini"></textarea>
                    </div> -->
                </div>
                <!-- <div class="top-10-min">
                    <a href="#" class="button button-red button-rounded button-full button-sm ultrabold uppercase shadow-small top-0">KIRIM SEKARANG</a>
                </div> -->
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    const app2 = new Vue({
        el: '#app2',
        data:{
            bidComments:{},
            commentBox:'',
            item :{!! $pet->toJson()!!},
            user :{!! Auth::user()->toJson()!!}
        },
        mounted(){
        this.getComments();
        },
        methods: {
            getComments(){
                axios.get('/api/items/'+this.item.id+'/comments')
                .then((response)=>{
                    this.bidComments = response.data
                })
                .catch(function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                });
               var a =  Echo.channel('item.'+this.item.id)
                .listen ('NewBidComment',(e)=>{
                    console.log(e.bidComments);
                })
                console.log(a);
            },
            postComment(){
                axios.post('/api/items/'+this.item.id+'/comment', {
                    api_token:this.user.api_token,
                    comment:this.commentBox
                })
                .then((response)=>{
                    this.bidComments.unshift(response.data);
                    this.commentBox = '';
                })
                .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          })
            },
            listen(){
                Echo.channel('item.'.this.item.id)
                .listen ('NewBidComment',(e)=>{
                    console.log(e.bidComments);
                });
            }
      }
    })
</script>
```

**channels.php**

```
> Broadcast::channel('item.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
>  return $user->id == \App\Item::find($id)->user_id; });
```

**My Event**

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\BidComment; use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel; use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels; use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel; use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel; use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable; use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets; use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast; use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcastNow;

class NewBidComment implements ShouldBroadcastNow {
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    public $bidComment;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(BidComment $bidComment)
    {
        $this->bidComment = $bidComment;
    }

/**
 * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
 */
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new Channel('item.' . $this->bidComment->item->id);
}

public function broadcastWith()
{
    return [
        'comment' => $this->bidComment->comment,
        'created_at' => $this->bidComment->created_at->toFormattedDateString(),
        'user' => [
            'name' => $this->bidComment->user->name,
        ]
    ];
} }
```

**My controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\BidComment;
use App\Item;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Events\NewBidComment;

class BidCommentController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Item $item)
    {
        return response()->json($item->bidComments()->with('user')->latest()->get());
    }

    public function store(Request $request, Item $item)
    {
        $comment = $item->bidComments()->create([
            'comment' => $request->comment,
            'user_id' => Auth::id()
        ]);

        $comment = BidComment::where('id', $comment->id)->with('user')->first();
        broadcast(new NewBidComment($comment))->toOthers();
        return $comment->toJson();
    }
}
```

MY big question is where is the error when i push a message nothing wrong but doesn't real time(for other), and in the websocket dashboard my chanel not being subscribe.

Comment: You didn't subscribe to channel i think. Try to put `Echo.listen` in vue `created` hook

Comment: it dosn' work cause im not using vue commponent, idk something wrong with my controller or event or channel, please any suggest

Comment: this my error when im using listen

Comment: pusher.min.js:8 WebSocket connection to 'ws:/mydomain/app/anyKey?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.3.1&flash=false' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Did you run websocket listener on server?

Comment: yes i'm. Using beyondCode websockets

Comment: are you trying to run it on live server or local server ?

Comment: in my own server(live)

Answer (score 0):

Edit your bootstrap.js and try this out. I was struggling with the same error for 2-3 days when I worked with websockets. When you use websockets in live server you must use https and define your ssl certificates path to websockets.php.

Checkout below configuration. Also make sure your ssl certificate path has proper read-write access.

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    encrypted: false,
    wssPort: 6001,
    disableStats: true,
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
    auth: {
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': window.App.csrfToken,
        },
    },
});
```

also edit your config/broadcasting.php

```
'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'encrypted' => false,
                'port' => 6001,
                'scheme' => 'https',
                'curl_options' => [
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
                ]
            ],
        ],
```

Then open config/websockets.php

```
 'ssl' => [
        /*
         * Path to local certificate file on filesystem. It must be a PEM encoded file which
         * contains your certificate and private key. It can optionally contain the
         * certificate chain of issuers. The private key also may be contained
         * in a separate file specified by local_pk.
         */
        'local_cert' => 'local_certificate_key_path', // fullchain.pem

        /*
         * Path to local private key file on filesystem in case of separate files for
         * certificate (local_cert) and private key.
         */
        'local_pk' => 'your_private_key_path', // privkey.pem

        /*
         * Passphrase for your local_cert file.
         */
        'passphrase' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_PASSPHRASE', null),

        'verify_peer' => false,
    ],
```

Comment: what your domain.com/laravel-websockets console says ?

Comment: pusher.min.js:8 WebSocket connection to 'ws:/mydomain/app/anyKey?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.3.1&flash=false' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: in my dashboard websockets

Comment: Check my answer bro. edited. hopefully it will solve your issue

Comment: A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://pusher.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

Comment: they are still try to connect on pusher.com? any suggest

Comment: At first try clearing your cookies and caches of browser 
if not working then,
See this tutorial and follow step by step: 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pIGy7-7gGXI